# How GAM regression (mgcv) deals with repeated values?

Tags: r, na, gam, mgcv, non-repetitive

I am trying to explore regressions between abundances and 3 variables. My data (test.gam)looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Site   Abundance      SPM isotherm SiOH4
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 cycle1     0.769 5960367.    102.   18.2
2 cycle1     0.632 6496360.     97.5  18.2
3 cycle1     0.983 5328652.    105    18.2
4 cycle1     1     6212034.    110    18.2
5 cycle1     0.821 5468987.    105    18.2
6 cycle1     0.734 5280549.    112.   18.2
```

In one of these variable (SiOH4), I have only one value per Site, while for the 2 other variables, I have single value for each station (each row being a station).

To plot the relation between abundances and SiOH4 I would simply compute a mean value for each Site. The relation show that there is a constant increase of abundances with SiOH4 levels: [Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P5qN.png).

Now I tried running a GAM on this data using the following code:

```
mod_gam1 <- gam(Abundance ~ s(isotherm, bs = "cr", k = 5)
+ SPM + s(SiOH4, bs = "cr", k = 5), data = test.gam, family = gaussian(link = log), gamma = 1.4)
```

giving me these results:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: log 

Formula:
Abundance ~ s(isotherm, bs = "cr", k = 5) + SPM + s(SiOH4, bs = "cr", 
    k = 5)

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -8.182e-01  8.244e-02  -9.925  < 2e-16 ***
SPM         -4.356e-08  1.153e-08  -3.778 0.000219 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
              edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(isotherm) 2.019  2.485 10.407 1.46e-05 ***
s(SiOH4)    3.861  3.986  9.823 1.01e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.492   Deviance explained = 51.2%
GCV = 0.044202  Scale est. = 0.040674  n = 177
```

So I am happy quite happy about the results but then by checking with `gam.check`, I find that k is too low.

```
Method: GCV   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 8 iterations.
Gradient range [-8.801477e-14,5.555545e-13]
(score 0.04420205 & scale 0.04067442).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [6.631202e-05,7.084933e-05].
Model rank =  10 / 10 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

              k'  edf k-index p-value    
s(isotherm) 4.00 2.02    0.85    0.01 ** 
s(SiOH4)    4.00 3.86    0.59  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Note that I voluntarily set my k to 5, otherwise there is an overfit of the pattern.

I thought that this might due to the fact that many of the values in `SiOH4` are repeated. By modifying my data to keep only the first value of each Site (replacing all other rows with NA) like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Site [1]
  Site   Abundance      SPM isotherm SiOH4
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 cycle1     0.769 5960367.    102.   18.2
2 cycle1     0.632 6496360.     97.5  NA  
3 cycle1     0.983 5328652.    105    NA  
4 cycle1     1     6212034.    110    NA  
5 cycle1     0.821 5468987.    105    NA  
6 cycle1     0.734 5280549.    112.   NA
```

I hoped preventing this repeated levels. But this way I am also loosing most of my rows, with the `na.omit` option on. However running the same GAM, I don't have problems with k being too low after using `gam.check`.

So do I need to keep repetitive values and ignore the warning from `gam.check` or there is a way to somehow keep all rows even if NA exist?

Comment: NA are actually automatically remove when running the GAM. I kind of solved the issue by measuring a mean value to fill up the gap when possible.

Comment: I think you'd be better off treating SiOH4 as (ordered) factor and perhaps having a different smooth per level. Or just replicate the SiOH4 values as required and refit, but I doubt you can do much with a smooth that you can't with an ordered factor when you have only a few unique values.